# photo upload on flickr not working using swift3

Tags: swift, flickr

I am trying to upload a Picture on Flickr using swift3. Please have a look at my code and suggest.

Here is the link to the service:

flickr.com/services/api/upload.api.html

flickr.com/services/api/upload.example.html

I have Implemented the OAuth for Flickr here is the link to my sample project on Github. https://github.com/uditajmera/FlickSwift3Demo

```
public func uploadPhotosURLs1(lobjImageToUpload:UIImage)
{
  let secret =  FlickrManager.sharedInstance.strAuthSecret
  //where secret is 7e5cfde9b0023627
  let api_key = FlickrManager.sharedInstance.strApiKey
  let auth_token = FlickrManager.sharedInstance.strAuthToken

  let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(lobjImageToUpload, 1)

  let uploadSig = "\(secret)_key\(api_key)_token\(auth_token)"
  let request = NSMutableURLRequest()
  let url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/upload/"
  request.url = URL(string: url)!
  request.httpMethod = "POST"


  let boundary = String("---------------------------7d44e178b0434")
  request.addValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

  let body:NSMutableData = NSMutableData()
  body.append("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

  body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"api_key\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
  body.append("\(api_key)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
  body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
  body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"auth_token\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
  body.append("\(auth_token)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

  body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
  body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"api_sig\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
  body.append("\(uploadSig)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
  body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
  body.append(String("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\"; filename=\"photo.jpg\"\r\n").data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
  body.append("Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

  body.append(imageData!)
  body.append("\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
  request.httpBody = body as Data

  let session = URLSession.shared

  let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest,
                            completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
      if let error = error {
        print(error)
      }
      if let data = data{
        print("data =\(data)")
      }
      if let response = response {
        print("url = \(response.url!)")
        print("response = \(response)")
        let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
        print("response code = \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
        print("DATA = \(data)")
        //if you response is json do the following
        do{
            let resultJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions())
            let arrayJSON = resultJSON as! NSArray
            for value in arrayJSON{
                let dicValue = value as! NSDictionary
                for (key, value) in dicValue {
                    print("key = \(key)")
                    print("value = \(value)")
                }
            }

        }catch _{
            print("Received not-well-formatted JSON")
        }
    }
})
    task.resume()
}
```

Expected response is in XML like :- "<*photoid > 1234 <*/photoid>"

getting this response:

```
response =
 <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x618000223c00> { 
 URL:http://api.flickr.com/services/upload/ } { status code: 200, headers {
Age = 14;
"Cache-Control" = private;
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Encoding" = gzip;
"Content-Length" = 117;
"Content-Type" = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Tue, 13 Dec 2016 07:55:13 GMT";
P3P = "policyref=\"https://policies.yahoo.com/w3c/p3p.xml\", CP=\"CAO DSP COR CUR ADM DEV TAI PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi TELo OTPi OUR DELi SAMi OTRi UNRi PUBi IND PHY ONL UNI PUR FIN COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA POL HEA PRE LOC GOV\"";
Server = ATS;
Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
Via = "http/1.1 r01.ycpi.inc.yahoo.net (ApacheTrafficServer [cMsSf ])";
"X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN;
"X-Robots-Tag" = noindex;
"X-Served-By" = "up8.flickr.bf1.yahoo.com";
   } }
```

Comment: Status code 200 sounds good. Are you sure you're showing the response body here?

Comment: Yes @Pekka웃 u can check by yourself. I shared my project on github https://github.com/uditajmera/FlickSwift3Demo

Comment: Pekka 웃 here is the link of  the service example :-  https://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.example.html